# Ability to protect questions on Meta and Main

Tags: support

I recently passed 15k, and apparently that gives me an extra privilege.

[image: You've gained the privilege - protect questions]

I can see that I can do that in Meta:

[image: Protect link]

But I don't seem to be able to do that on the main site:

[image]

Have I misinterpreted something? Both sites are showing the same rep number. I couldn't find anything on meta.SO about this difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a non-moderator, you have to wait 24 hours before you can protect a question.

Comment: Aha. Thanks: I didn't look back far enough in the main site. It would be nice for that restriction to be documented somewhere and easily found, though.

Comment: What Andrew said. How come *you* know this, tchrist?

Comment: @FumbleFingers It is just the way it works. I thought everyone knew. The original request and the status-completed bit is on MSO, with such details included.

Comment: Each individual user would presumably only have a single 24-hour window in which to even be aware of anything odd going on. I can't imagine that many would notice in the first place - and most of those that *did* would probably just shrug their shoulders and forget about it after the next day (by which time it would be a "non-issue"). There aren't *that* many ELU users who could be affected anyway. Whatever - there's at least an argument for saying if *you* could find the MSO original, you should include a link here (maybe we could close this one as a **duplicate!** :)